# How do I fix 'Setup project with custom action file not found' exception?

Tags: windows-services, setup-project, custom-action, ssis

I am trying to create a setup project for a Windows Service. I've followed the directions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816169 to create the setup project with no trouble.

I want to be able to get a value during the installation in order to update the app.config with the user's desired settings. I added a *Textboxes (A)* dialog to retrieve the values. I set the *Edit1Property* property to "TIMETORUN", and in my Primary Output action's *CustomActionData* property I put in the following: */TimeToRun="[TIMETORUN]\"*. So far so good. Running the setup I can retrieve the *TimeToRun* value from the *Context.Parameters* collection without issue.

In order to locate the app.config I need to also pass in the value of the *TARGETDIR* Windows Installer Property to my custom action. This is where things begin to fall apart. In order to achieve this, the above *CustomActionData* must be altered like so: */TimeToRun="[TIMETORUN]\" /TargetDir="[TARGETDIR]\"*. Now when I run the setup I get the following error message:

> Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Files' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

If you google this problem you will inevitably find people having tremendous success by simply adding the trailing slash to the */TargetDir="[TARGETDIR]\"* portion of the *CustomActionData*. This unfortunately does not solve my issue.

I tried so many different variations of the *CustomActionData* string and none of them worked. I tried logging to a file from my overridden *Install* method to determine where the breakage was, but no log file is created because it's not even getting that far. As the error indicates, the failure is during the Initialization step.

I have a hunch that it could be one of the dependencies that the setup project is trying to load. Perhaps somehow something is being appended to the *CustomActionData* string and isn't playing well with the *TARGETDIR* value (which contains spaces, i.e. "C:\Program Files\My Company\Project Name"). Again, this is another hunch that I cannot seem to confirm due to my inability to debug the setup process.

One further thing to mention, and yes it's another hunch, could this be an issue with Setup Projects on 64-bit version of Windows? I'm running Windows 7 Professional.

I'll provide names of the dependencies in case it helps:

- Microsoft .NET Framework
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DtsMsg.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll
- Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.msxml6_interop.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll
- Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlTDiagM.dll

As you may glean from the dependencies, the Windows Service is scheduling a call to a DTSX package.

Sorry for the long rant. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hi folks, I am facing same problem/issue/error since last morning. Only the difference is I have set one Installation folder to install service files in folder, but I am not able to get value in [TARGETDIR], everything else is working fine. [TARGETDIR] always getting blank.**Please need urgent help in this.**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer is so maddeningly simple. If the last argument in the `CustomActionData` is going to contain spaces and thus you have to surround it with quotes and a trailing slash, you must also have a space following the trailing slash, like this:

```
/TimeToRun="[TIMETORUN]\" /TargetDir="[TARGETDIR]\ "
```

The solution and explanation can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/4c71d619-5322-4734-89f3-5c1997e42b93/).

Comment: Thanks man! Would have taken me loong time to find out, or perhaps I would have given up given my other issues with this bastardized, evil technology. (MSI)

Comment: Also, the trick to getting a log file for your custom action is to add the switches */LogFile=<filename> /LogToConsole=true* to the CustomActionData property for the custom action.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue.  In my case, it was odd because my installer had ran successfully once, then I uninstalled my app via Add/Remove Programs successfully, did some coding (did NOT touch my *CustomActionData* string), and rebuilt my project and setup project.  It was when I re-ran my MSI that I got this error.

The coding I had done was to bring in more values of more parameters I had been specifying in my *CustomActionData* string.  That syntax for getting the parameter values (i.e. `string filepath = Context.Paramenters["filepath"]`), which was in my Installer class, was actually fine, but as I found out, the syntax of the later parameters I was now trying to get from my *CustomActionData* string had not been correct, from the very beginning.  I had failed to add a second quote around one of those parameters, so nothing else could be obtained.

I was using the "Textboxes (A)" and "Textboxes (B)" windows in the User Interface section.  A has 1 box, `EDITA1`, where I get the path to a file, and B has 2 boxes, `EDITB1` and `EDITB2`, for some database parameters.  My *CustomActionData* string looked like this:

```
/filepath="[EDITA1]" /host="[EDITB1] /port="[EDITB2]"
```

It should have been:

```
/filepath="[EDITA1]" /host="[EDITB1]" /port="[EDITB2]"
```

(closing quote on `[EDITB1]`)